# Get names of functions injected into CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am using the technique detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624777/21960) to manage a library of small utility functions. (Essentially, each function is loaded as a "mix-in" using `cfinclude`.)

I have need, however, to know the names of the functions that the object has (once instantiated). A `cfdump` on the object only shows the `init` function which is written directly in the CFC.

Some more detail:

I am creating the object in the application scope in OnApplicationStart().

```
<cfset application.udfs=createObject("component","extensions.udfs").init()>
```

However, to save the developers from having to constantly write `application.udfs.foo()`, I thought I'd grab all of the functions and drop them in to the variables scope in OnRequestStart(), so that these hypothetical developers could just write `foo()`.

```
<cfset foo=application.udfs.foo>
```

Obviously, though, this needs to be dynamic and to happen for each of the functions in the object, no matter how many there are. If I repeat this line for every function I've lost whatever I'd gained by having a library that is dynamically generated.

I thought perhaps I could use a collection loop, but that was invalid. I am fairly certain there's a way to get the list of methods in an object, but I have not yet been able to find it.

Any clues?

By the by, my fallback is going to be to copy the application.udfs object to a local object with a nice short name (like "u") so that the developers can simply type `u.foo()`, so no need to suggest that if what I want to do can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should allow you to import all your udfs into the global variables scope:

```
StructAppend(variables, application.udfs);
```

Comment: This is very strange... But smart.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GetMetaData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dd9.html) should help you.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder! Unfortunately, the array of functions it returns is just the `init`, like I saw with `cfdump`.

Comment: @AlEverett Oops! This is because I'm using Railo. It is smart enough to expose included chunks of CFC, both for `cfdump` and `GetMetaData`.

Answer (score 1):

Here another interesting option suggested by [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com):

Check out the detail in his blog entry: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1776-Creating-Globally-Accessible-User-Defined-Functions-In-ColdFusion-Safer-Version-.htm

UDF.cfc

```
<cfcomponent
    output="false"
    hint="I define user defined functions.">

    <cffunction
        name="getMessage"
        access="public"
        returntype="string"
        output="false"
        hint="I return a test message.">

        <cfreturn "I am defined in the UDF component" />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Application.cfc

```
<!--- Define the application. --->
<cfset this.name = hash( getCurrentTemplatePath() ) />
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 5, 0 ) />


<!---
    Add all of our "global" methods to the URL scope. Since
    ColdFusion will automatically seach the URL scope for
    non-scoped variables, it will find our non-scoped method
    names.
--->
<cfset structAppend(
    url,
    createObject( "component", "UDF" )
    ) />
```