# Coldfusion: Access data from another site

Tags: coldfusion

I have coldfusion application and currently I am two  site under the same folder.

1. Root

   - Site 1.

     - Site1: Application.cfc.
   - Site 2

     - Site2: Application.cfc.

Both are using two different sessions.

I want to access a function of Site2 in Site1 but having problems because of the different session.

I had even tried accessing data through scope variable but that also didnt work.

Is there any solution to do this or is it not possible?

Is there any possibility to get name of the application on function. So, that the function can know which application is making the request.

Ex: If function of Site2 get request from Site2 then dont ignore session variable, but ignore if Site1 is making the request

Comment: Are these sites on the same server?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this related question - [How do you organize your small reusable cffunctions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/624777/1636917)

Comment: Yes they are under the same saver

Answer (score 0):

Set up a sub directory in site 2 for external access which handles sessions differently than the root folder of site 2.